# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined in object

Tags: javascript, error-handling

I don't know what I am missing here, can you please help me.

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>    
<html>
<head>
    <title>SNOW</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>  
<div id="snowDiv">*</div>
</body>
<script>
    var SNOW = function () {
        this.top = 0;
        this.left = 0;
        this.snowflake = document.getElementById('snowDiv');
        this.snowflake.style.margin         = this.top+'px 0px 0px '+this.left+'px';
        this.snowflake.style.positon        = 'absolute';
        this.snowflake.style.zIndex         = '1';
        this.snowflake.style.position       = 'absolute';
        this.snowflake.style.height         = '5px';
        this.snowflake.style.width          = '5px';
        this.moveSnow = function () {
            SNOW.top += 2;
            SNOW.left += 5;
            SNOW.snowflake.style.margin = SNOW.top+'px 0px 0px '+SNOW.left+'px';
            window.requestAnimationFrame(SNOW.moveSnow);
        };
    };
    var snowing = new SNOW();
    snowing.moveSnow();
</script>
```

If I put the moveSnow function outside the SNOW object it works, but like that it does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because `SNOW` refers to the object constructor, not the instance which is referenced by `this`. Create a variable referencing `this` i.e `that = this`. Now you can apply stuff to the instance in the method.

```js
 var SNOW = function () {
    this.top = 0;
    this.left = 0;
    this.snowflake = document.getElementById('snowDiv');
    this.snowflake.style.margin         = this.top+'px 0px 0px '+this.left+'px';
    this.snowflake.style.positon        = 'absolute';
    this.snowflake.style.zIndex         = '1';
    this.snowflake.style.position       = 'absolute';
    this.snowflake.style.height         = '5px';
    this.snowflake.style.width          = '5px';
    var that = this;
    this.moveSnow = function () {
        that.top += 2;
        that.left += 5;
        that.snowflake.style.margin = that.top+'px 0px 0px '+that.left+'px';
        window.requestAnimationFrame(that.moveSnow);
    };
};
var snowing = new SNOW();
snowing.moveSnow();
```

```html
<div id="snowDiv">*</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is the problem with your variable scope....
check jsbin link here... 
    http://jsbin.com/keyaze/1/edit?html,output

Comment: `SNOW.top += 2; SNOW.left += 5;` are probably not the intended code.

Comment: yes you are correct... I dint change coz, he may have different requirement with that variable...